Google Sheets - Multiple dropdown menus
I have some problem with the code.. I'm stuck on the third statement if "Overheights".
I want to be able to sort by 'Pick','Error' and 'Overheights', but for the latter it doesn't work exactly as planned? any ideas?
Pick works fine
and Overheights nope..
=QUERY(AA1:AL, "select * where 1=1 " & 
       IF(B1="all", "", "and AA='" & B1 & "' ") & 
       IF(E1="all", "", "and AH='" & E1 & "' ") & 
       IF(K1="", "", "and AB='" & K1 & "' ") & 
       IF(H1="Overheights", "and AK='" & H1 & "' ", "") & 
       "order by " & 
       IF(H1="Pick", "AI", IF(H1="Error", "AJ", IF(H1="Overheights", "AK", "AJ"))) & 
       " DESC limit 10",1)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gIgdWEpJdBWxUKKIvdZhlX2lt4-XHzSen0pN9KTJQJU/edit?usp=sharing
I tried few things but no ideas..


Column_AK consists of just numbers but the following if condition is trying to find the text Overheights in this column. Either remove this statement completely OR change it to something that would be both true/false
IF(H1="Overheights", "and AK='" & H1 & "' ", "") &


try:
=QUERY(AA1:AL, "where 1=1 " & 
 IF(B1="all",, "and AA='"& B1 &"'")& 
 IF(E1="all",, "and AH='"& E1 &"'")& 
 IF(K1="",, "and AB='"& K1 &"'") & 
 IF(H1="Overheights", "and AK <> '0'", )& 
 "order by " & 
 IF(H1="Pick", "AI", 
 IF(H1="Error", "AJ", 
 IF(H1="Overheights", "AK", "AJ")))& 
 " desc limit 10", 1)


